# TFS 2008: How do I setup a Build Server

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Can someone point me to documentation on setting up a TFS 2008 build server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Installing Team Foundation Build" in this download

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=FF12844F-398C-4FE9-8B0D-9E84181D9923&displaylang=en

Answer (score 2):

[TFS 2008 Setup and Administration FAQs](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfssetup/thread/568daed8-0d29-46c0-8510-5e274e8b5ebf)

- [TFS 2008: A basic guide to Team Build 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/archive/2007/08/14/tfs-2008-a-basic-guide-to-team-build-2008.aspx)
- [How To: Set Up a Continuous Integration Build in Visual Studio Team Foundation Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668971.aspx)
- [Continuous Integration with Visual Studio 2008 (“Orcas”) Team Foundation Server](http://blogs.msdn.com/ireland/archive/2007/06/25/continuous-integration-with-visual-studio-2008-orcas-team-foundation-server.aspx)

Comment: Those are some great links for using a build server. But what I'm looking for is how to create a build server.